# adding a block in <checkout_cart_index>

Tags: checkout, layout

I am trying to add a block to `<checkout_cart_index>` after `name="checkout.cart.totals"` I have managed to add my block after the content area.

But I would like to add it immediately after "grand total". After reading [this page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/controlling-block-order) I tried this

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mdeprojects_discount/remainder" name="mdeprojects.remainder" template="discount/remainder.phtml" after="-" name="checkout.cart" />
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Which gives me an error (name="checkout.cart.totals" gives the same error)

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 21: parser error : Attribute name redefined

A another attempt I made was

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mdeprojects_discount/remainder" name="mdeprojects.remainder" template="discount/remainder.phtml" after="checkout.cart.totals" />
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

this still displays the block after the content area.

How do I add my block after "grand total" and why won't my method work?

Comment: For clarity, I would assume the simplexml error is due to the block having the `name` attribute defined twice, as opposed to the block having a name attribute value the same as its parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naming the block `checkout.cart` will cause a conflict because the parent block also has this name.

To add the block in the place you want, after the totals use the following XML

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="mdeprojects_discount/remainder" name="mdeprojects.remainder" as="mdeprojects.remainder" template="discount/remainder.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Then check the file `template/checkout/cart.phtml` on line 151. Here you can see `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>`. Place the following code on the next line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mdeprojects.remainder'); ?>
```

Comment: after attribute is really required ? Since he is calling directly block output into template. I mean, the new block will be where the `getChildHtml` is called nevertheless.

Comment: You're right, it's not. Updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it has not worked. I tried, then copied and pasted your code to make sure it was not a typo.

Comment: try using `core/template` as a type to see if it's an error in the block and make sure your template exists. Also turn of cache and compiling

Comment: I have tried core/template as you suggested and got the same results. The block outputs fine (but in the wrong place) if i use <reference name="content">

Comment: Please use `<reference name="checkout.cart">`

Comment: Make sure you're putting the call to `getChildHtml` in the correct template file. I can't recall how many times I've been wondering why something won't work when it was simply overlooking the fact that I was editing the wrong template file.

Comment: @SanderMangel Apologies, you were correct! I was checking in design/frontend/base/default/template. I had forgot I was in my own theme and that I had been advised to add a default folder to my theme which contained all the same folders as base/default

Comment: No worries. Glad it works now. Always good to use template hints to check what phtml file you should modify and in what directory